# .NET Custom UserControl with Structured/Multi-level Properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls, properties, custom-controls

I can create a Custom UserControl with simple properties (Integer, String, etc) and have those properties show up in the Property Panel. I can also create a Custom UserControl with properties like Size, Rectangle, etc and the properties will show up as an expandable item in the Property Panel (click on the '+' and the Size expands to Width & Height).

Is it possible to create properties with my own custom structure? e.g. Property 'Message' expands to Text, ForeColor, BackColor, Blink etc. I have tried creating a property that references a simple class or structure with containing the properties representing my custom structure but in the Property Panel the property is greyed out and cannot be expanded or modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provider a `TypeConverter` for your custom type so that it can be converted to and from a string, and then decorate your custom type with the `TypeConverterAttribute`.

Derive your TypeConverter from `ExpandableObjectConverter`.

```
public class MyTypeConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
}
```

Override `CanConvertTo()`, `ConvertTo()`, `CanConvertFrom()`, and `ConvertFrom()` to provide the ability to convert the custom type to a string (this is the value that appears in the property grid on the main row which you can see before expanding) and from a string back to itself. A common string representation would be to show a list of all the field values separated by commas.

Decorate the custom type with the `TypeConverterAttribute`.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyTypeConverter ))]
public struct MyType
{
}
```

That's the bare minimum to get you started. There is considerably more to learn. [This MDSN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Just a followup. I found it was also necessary to add the following attribute to each of my properties to allow the designer to properly save the property values.<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>